# css apply style if parent width more than specific value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, web

Want to apply css selectors if only parent element width more than specific value.
CSS must not use media query to implement this because no relation between viewport width and the parent div width.

Javascript is welcome but avoid continuous width check please.
Ex.

```
<style>

/*  something like that  div[width>400px]  */
   .parent div[width>400px]{
       background:red;
    }


</style>


<!--ok width is more than 400 so apply style to child div-->
<div class="parent" style="width:500px;"> 
    <div>

    </div>
</div>


<!--width is still less than 400 so don;t apply styles-->
<div class="parent" style="width:300px;"> 
    <div>

    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The Resize event only works on the window element.

Vanilla JavaScript would be something like this.

```
var parentDivTriggrtWidth = 400;
var childDivClassNames = ["red", "blue"];

window.addEventListener("load", function(e){
    var list = document.getElementsByClassName("parent");
    for(var i=0; i<list.length; i++){
        var parentDiv = list[i];
        parentDiv.resizeParent = function(width){
            if(typeof width!="undefined"){ this.style.width = width+"px"; }
            var k = this.clientWidth > parentDivTriggrtWidth ? 1 : 0;
            this.children[0].className = childDivClassNames[k];
// Debug only
this.children[0].innerHTML = "Parent Size: "+this.clientWidth+"<br />Class: "+this.children[0].className;
        }
        window.addEventListener("resize", function(e){ parentDiv.resizeParent(); },false);
        parentDiv.resizeParent();
    }
},false);
```

> Look at the snippet in "fullpage"

```js
var parentDivTriggrtWidth = 400;
var childDivClassNames = ["red", "blue"];

window.addEventListener("load", function(e){
 var list = document.getElementsByClassName("parent");
 for(var i=0; i<list.length; i++){
  var parentDiv = list[i];
  parentDiv.resizeParent = function(width){
   if(typeof width!="undefined"){ this.style.width = width+"px"; }
   var k = this.clientWidth > parentDivTriggrtWidth ? 1 : 0;
   this.children[0].className = childDivClassNames[k];
// Debug only
this.children[0].innerHTML = "Parent Size: "+this.clientWidth+"<br />Class: "+this.children[0].className;
  }
  window.addEventListener("resize", function(e){ parentDiv.resizeParent(); },false);
  parentDiv.resizeParent();
 }
},false);
```

```css
.parent {
  border: 3px solid #aaaaaa;
}
.parent div {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  color: white
}
.red {
  background-color: red;
}
.blue {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<h3>width 500px (resize by JavaScript)</h3>

<div id="p1" class="parent" style="width:500px;">
  <div></div>
</div>

<button type="button" onclick="document.getElementById('p1').resizeParent(800)">Resize +</button>
<button type="button" onclick="document.getElementById('p1').resizeParent(200)">Resize -</button>
<button type="button" onclick="document.getElementById('p1').resizeParent(500)">Reset</button>

<hr />

<h3>width 100% (resize window)</h3>

<!--width is still less than 400 so don;t apply styles-->
<div id="p2" class="parent" style="width:100%;">
  <div></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

if i got you right...

JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var ParentWidth = $('.parent').width();
    if (ParentWidth > 400) {
        $('.parent').addClass('newstyle');
    }
});
```

CSS:

```
.newstyle
{
    background: red;
    /*** add more css ***/
}
```

i Recommends you to use class because you can add more css to the class later.

Comment: ok, that's right but what about changing the parent size?
If i changed parent width by javascript to less than 400px  the style will persist.

Comment: the question is when...if do you mean to change parent on resize so you can use the resize jquery function to check the width and add or remove the class depends on the result....

Comment: the parent div width can be changed only by 
1.innerHTML change 
2.Other css classes
3.Javascript. 
so it has no relation to on resize event.

Comment: so all the possible changes are on load? (not events)

Answer (score 0):

jQuery is an option :

```
 $( document ).ready(function() {
if ($(".parent").width() > 700) {
$('.parent').css("background-color", "red");
}
});
```